# Subset numbers from list

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have such a kind of output from `knnCV.cv_results_` (using `GridSearchCV` function). How can I fill or modify this code `k_grid = resCV[??].data` to get only numbers (1, 2, ..., 48) from this list?

```
 my_dict = {'params': [{'n_neighbors': 1},
  {'n_neighbors': 2},
  {'n_neighbors': 3},
  {'n_neighbors': 4},
  .
  .
  .
  {'n_neighbors': 47},
  {'n_neighbors': 48}]},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
my_dict = {'params': [{'n_neighbors': 1},
  {'n_neighbors': 2},
  {'n_neighbors': 3},
  {'n_neighbors': 4},
  {'n_neighbors': 47},
  {'n_neighbors': 48}]}



for i in range(0,len(my_dict['params'])):
   print( my_dict['params'][i]['n_neighbors'] , end =",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
n_neighbors_list = list(map(itemgetter('n_neighbors'), my_dict['params']))

print(n_neighbors_list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 47, 48]
```